# Terraform: correct way to attach AWS managed policies to a role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, terraform

I want to attach one of the pre-existing AWS managed roles to a policy, here's my current code:

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "sto-readonly-role-policy-attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.sto-test-role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
}
```

Is there a better way to model the managed policy and then reference it instead of hardcoding the ARN?  It just seems like whenever I hardcode ARNs / paths or other stuff like this, I usually find out later there was a better way.

Is there something already existing in Terraform that models managed policies?  Or is hardcoding the ARN the "right" way to do it?

Comment: Yes, hardcore with pre-existing AWS managed roles is the right way, otherwise, you can define the similar policy and attach it.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The [IAM Policy data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/iam_policy.html) is great for this. A data resource is used to describe data or resources that are not actively managed by Terraform, but are referenced by Terraform.

For your example, you would create a data resource for the managed policy as follows:

```hcl
data "aws_iam_policy" "ReadOnlyAccess" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
}
```

The name of the data source, `ReadOnlyAccess` in this case, is entirely up to you. For managed policies I use the same name as the policy name for the sake of consistency, but you could just as easily name it `readonly` if that suits you.

You would then attach the IAM policy to your role as follows:

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "sto-readonly-role-policy-attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.sto-test-role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${data.aws_iam_policy.ReadOnlyAccess.arn}"
}
```

Comment: seems this doesn't always work, for example `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`

Comment: @Bill - watch out for resources that get "auto-created" for you by the AWS console (as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/38428834/924597).  No idea if that's the problem you're having, just thought I'd mention the possibility.

Comment: There are some `service-linked` role, for example, the sample is `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`. A feature request were raised by someone already: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6072

Comment: you can place the ARN in line having only one block for the attachment: resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "sto-readonly-role-policy-attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.sto-test-role.name}"
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"
}

Comment: I can confirm it works with `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole`

Comment: Can you please explain why this is better than hardcoding the arn into `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment`? You hardcode it in both cases.

Comment: @IkarPohorský it makes no difference to your infrastructure, but it does make a difference to tools that are built on top of terraform. If you create a data object, the dependency is tracked in terraform alongside all of your other resources. Internally, terraform is building a graph of your infrastructure. You can dump this graph with `terraform graph`. You'll see the data object in the output if it's tracked as a data dependency, but not if you hard code a string. If you have GraphViz installed, visualize it with `terraform graph | dot -Tsvg > graph.svg`.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the managed policy is already attached to the target role or not? say a check before attaching and attach only if it not already attach to the Role.

Answer (score 22):

When using values that Terraform itself doesn't directly manage, you have a few options.

The first, simplest option is to just hard-code the value as you did here. This is a straightforward answer if you expect that the value will never change. Given that these "canned policies" are documented, built-in AWS features they likely fit this criteria.

The second option is to create a Terraform module and hard-code the value into *that*, and then reference this module from several other modules. This allows you to manage the value centrally and use it many times. A module that contains only outputs is a common pattern for this sort of thing, although you could also choose to make a module that contains an `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` resource with the role set from a variable.

The third option is to place the value in some location that Terraform can retrieve values from, such as Consul, and then retrieve it from there using a data source. With only Terraform in play, this ends up being largely equivalent to the second option, though it means Terraform will re-read it on each refresh rather than only when you update the module using `terraform init -upgrade`, and thus this could be a better option for values that change often.

The fourth option is to use a specialized data source that can read the value directly from the source of truth. Terraform does not currently *have* a data source for fetching information on AWS managed policies, so this is not an option for your current situation, but can be used to fetch other AWS-defined data such as the AWS IP address ranges, service ARNs, etc.

Which of these is appropriate for a given situation will depend on how commonly the value changes, who manages changes to it, and on the availability of specialized Terraform data sources.

Comment: You can now implement this requirement using `data sources` in terraform. Other replies already describe this option in detail!

Answer (score 14):

I got a similar situation, and I don't want to use the `arn` in my `terraform` script for two reasons,

- If we do it on the Web console, we don't really look at the `arn`, we search the role name, then attach it to the role
- The `arn` is not easy to remember, looks like is not for human

I would rather use the policy name, but not the `arn`, here is my example

```
# Get the policy by name
data "aws_iam_policy" "required-policy" {
  name = "AmazonS3FullAccess"
}

# Create the role
resource "aws_iam_role" "system-role" {
  name = "data-stream-system-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
        Effect = "Allow"
        Sid    = ""
        Principal = {
          Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      },
    ]
  })
}


# Attach the policy to the role
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "attach-s3" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.system-role.name
  policy_arn = data.aws_iam_policy.required-policy.arn
}
```

Comment: Is this safe? Are managed policies guaranteed to be named uniquely?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a few years since the previous answers were given and I wanted to provide an alternative.

The `aws_iam_role` resource has a `managed_policy_arns` field where you can supply a list of AWS Managed Policy ARN strings. This is described in the [Terraform Registry documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role#managed_policy_arns), along with *caveats* on mixing different types of policy attachment methods. The actual ARN of AWS Managed Policies are unlikely to change, so I don't see a problem with referencing them like this.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "sto-readonly-role-policy-attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.sto-test-role.name}"
  managed_policy_arns = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/ReadOnlyAccess"]
}
```

Comment: This is a great tip...but note that you have to add `managed_policy_arns` to `aws_iam_role` and not `aws_iam_policy_attachment` as shown.