# Why isn't my Event Bridge rule executing my Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to create an Event Bridge rule that will run my Lambda function every 30 mins.
I based my code on this answer I found here on SO [Use terraform to set up a lambda function triggered by a scheduled event source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895315/use-terraform-to-set-up-a-lambda-function-triggered-by-a-scheduled-event-source)

Here is my terraform code:

monitoring/main.tf:

```
...

module "cloudwatch_event_rule" {
  source = "./cloudwatch_event_rule"
  extra_tags = local.extra_tags
}

module "lambda_function" {
  source = "./lambda_functions"
  extra_tags = local.extra_tags
  alb_names = var.alb_names
  slack_webhook_url = var.slack_webhook_url
  environment_tag = local.environment_tag
}

module "cloudwatch_event_target" {
  source = "./cloudwatch_event_target"
  lambda_function_arn = module.lambda_function.detect_bad_rejects_on_alb_lambda_arn
  cloudwatch_event_rule_name = module.cloudwatch_event_rule.cloudwatch_event_rule_name
  extra_tags = local.extra_tags
}
```

monitoring/lambda_functions/main.tf:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "detect_bad_rejects_on_alb" {
  filename         = var.filename
  function_name    = var.function_name
  role             = aws_iam_role.detect_bad_reject_on_alb.arn
  handler          = var.handler
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(var.filename)
  runtime          = var.runtime
  timeout          = var.timeout
  environment {
      ...    
  }

}
```

monitoring/cloudwatch_event_rule/main.tf

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "event_rule" {
    name = var.rule_name
    description = var.description
    schedule_expression = var.schedule_expression
    tags = ...
}
```

monitoring/cloudwatch_event_rule/variables.tf

```
...

variable "schedule_expression" {
  type = string
  default = "rate(30 minutes)"
}

...
```

monitoring/cloudwatch_event_target/main.tf

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "event_target" {
  arn   = var.lambda_function_arn
  rule  = var.cloudwatch_event_rule_name
  input = var.input
}
```

This ends up creating the lambda function and the event bridge rule with my lambda function as its target with the schedule expression `"rate(30 minutes)"` but the lambda function is never executed?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i am clueless about terraform but i have faced a similar problem for which i wrote an article maybe it can help https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/scheduling-lambda-with-aws-eventbridge/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you posted is seems that you are **not adding permissions** for invocations. Your code does not show creation of [aws_lambda_permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission) with proper rules. So you should add such permissions so that EventBridge can invoke your function (example):

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "event-invoke" {
    statement_id = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
    action = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    function_name = var.function_name
    principal = "events.amazonaws.com"
    source_arn = module.cloudwatch_event_rule.cloudwatch_event_rule_arn
}
```

Make sure `source_arn` correctly points to the ARN of your event rule.